# Return mvc response from Event Listener in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, session, events

I am working on an event-driven architecture in Spring, and would like to be able to return HTTP responses from an event listener. For example, given that I receive a request in a controller, I want to be able to emit an event from this controller, and return a response to the request from the event listener that receives the request. The event emission and reception is not difficult, as I can use EventListener and EventPublisher. However, I am having a hard time returning a value to the client from the event listener. Is there any way to do it?